# Multiple variable assignments in ifelse()

Tags: r, if-statement

What mistake I am making here? I am trying to assign `a` and `b` some value if either three of the statements are true. I am trying to use the `ifelse` statement:

```
ifelse(1==1||2==2||3==3, (a<-100,b<-100), (a<-1000,b<-1000))
```

But I get an error:

> Error: unexpected ',' in " ifelse(1==1||2==2||3==3,(a<-100,"

Edited:

In a more genraralized manner, there are two variables a and b that need to assigned different values depending on the conditions :if (x=="cat" or x=="dog" or x=="horse", then, a is 100 and b is 200, else, a is 500 and b is 1000)

Comment: There are issues with your code.  (1) Why are you using `||` and not `|`? (2) what do you expect the result to be when you're equating all equal values? (3) The expression assignments are not going to work in the arguments of `ifelse`, hence the error.  But you could do `a <- b <- ifelse(..., 100, 1000)` once you get the condition right.

Comment: Just do `if (1==1||2==2||3==3) { a<-100; b<-100; } else { a <- 1000; b <- 1000;}`. Do not confuse `ifelse` with `if ... else ...`, they are distinct.

Comment: Okay, I will get to a more generalized manner.  There are two variables a and b that need to assigned different values depending on the conditions :if (x=="cat" or x=="dog" or x=="horse", then, a is 100 and b is 200, else, a is 500 and b is 1000)

Comment: Then it sounds like you should use a standard `if()` then `else()` construct.

Comment: It sounds like you might benefit from creating a lookup table, rather than using `if/else` statments

Comment: Then you can simply left join with your table

Answer (score 2):

Answering the question nicely stated by OP in the comments:

> if (x=="cat" or x=="dog" or x=="horse", then, a is 100 and b is 200, else, a is 500 and b is 1000)

```
if (x == "cat" || x == "dog" || x == "horse") {
  a = 100
  b = 200 
} else {
  a = 500
  b = 1000
}
```

We can do a little better using `%in%` instead of `|` - works well especially if you have even more values to check

```
if (x %in% c("cat", "dog", "horse")) {
  a = 100
  b = 200 
} else {
  a = 500
  b = 1000
}
```

`ifelse` is a vectorized function that returns a vector. If you want to "do" things, or return more than 1 value for each test condition, `if(){}else{}` is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Two comments:

- `||` is the short-circuiting logical OR, it isn't vectorized and will only use the first element. If you used variables here you should get a warning about it.
- `ifelse` is a function, not flow control, so you should assign it's value to a variable, and not try to do the assignment inside the function arguments.

So I think what you really want would look more like:

`a <- b <- ifelse(1 == 1 | 2 == 2 | 3 == 3, 100, 1000)`

Answer (score 1):

You can think about `ifelse()` in R as a function that operates on 3 vectors:

1. vector of boolean values (TRUE, FALSE). This is the `1==3 | 2==2 | 3==3` part.
2. vector of elements that will be chosen when the first vector is TRUE. This is the `a <- 100` part.
3. vector of elements that will be chosen when the first vector is FALSE. This is the `a <- 1000` part.

And all 3 of the vectors should have the same length.

Here is a quick demonstration:

```
vec1 <- 1:10 > 3 & 1:10 < 7
> vec1
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

vec2 <- LETTERS[1:10]
> vec2
 [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J"

vec3 <- letters[1:10]
> vec3
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
```

`ifelse()` function will combine `vec2` and `vec3` into a new vector in which the elements are taken from `vec2` and `vec3` depending on the value of `vec1`.

```
ifelse(vec1, vec2, vec3)
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "D" "E" "F" "g" "h" "i" "j"
```

To better see how it works here is everything in a table form (suggested by @Gregor).

```
> rbind(vec1, vec2, vec3, result=ifelse(vec1, vec2, vec3))
       [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]    [,8]    [,9]    [,10]
vec1   "FALSE" "FALSE" "FALSE" "TRUE" "TRUE" "TRUE" "FALSE" "FALSE" "FALSE" "FALSE"
vec2   "A"     "B"     "C"     "D"    "E"    "F"    "G"     "H"     "I"     "J"
vec3   "a"     "b"     "c"     "d"    "e"    "f"    "g"     "h"     "i"     "j"
result "a"     "b"     "c"     "D"    "E"    "F"    "g"     "h"     "i"     "j"
```

---

The problem with the approach you tried is that the `ifelse()` was misunderstood. You tried to assign values instead of providing the 2nd and 3rd vectors to the `ifelse()` function.

In your case the solution still using `ifelse()` would be to do it two times:

```
a <- ifelse(x=="cat" | x=="dog" | x=="horse", 100, 500)
b <- ifelse(x=="cat" | x=="dog" | x=="horse", 200, 1000)
```

---

NOTE: in the example above a single value `100` was provided instead of a vector. But R will expand it's length to match the length of the first vector. So single values are acceptable but are expanded to a vector under the hood.