# How I convert this data frame to a binary form?

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

Good afternoon

I have this data frame

```
> head(d)
  Gene.Name                  GO.term
1     EPCAM       cell-cell adhesion
2     CDH17            cell adhesion
3    LGALS4            cell adhesion
4    GPRC5A       cell-cell adhesion
5     KRT18       cell-cell adhesion
6      SOX9 cytoskeleton organsation
> 
CGN cell-cell adhesion

> unique(d$GO.term)
[1] cell-cell adhesion       cell adhesion           
[3] cytoskeleton organsation oxidation-reduction     
4 Levels: cell-cell adhesion ... oxidation-reduction
>
```

I want something like below where if a gene is in a GO.term that achieves 1 if not 0

```
> head(d[,1:2])
                             cell adhesion cytoskeleton organsation
AQP9                                          0               1
AXIN2                                         1               0
BCL6                                          1               0
BMP7                                          1               0
C5AR1                                         0               1
CCL2                                          0               1
>
```

But I don't know how to do that

Any help please?

Comment: Or just use `ifelse`/`case_when` and reshape.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428476/multiple-variable-assignments-in-ifelse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

d$cell.cell.adhesion<-df$Go.Term == “cell-cell adhesion”
…
d$organization<-d$Go.Term==“organization”

Create new column for each within group . Returned value is logical(which you can convert to integer if so desired)

*will convert all T/F values to integer [1,0]

```
#where ‘d’ is your data.frame
d*1
```

(On ipad or id give a larger example) but this should work

> Example
>   Say my dataframe is:

```
ColA        ColB 
A               sun
B              moon
```

Now, I want to create a new column(observation) that checks for the presence of a value (either ‘sun’ or ‘moon’)

mydataframe$NewCol<-mydataframe$ColB==‘sun’

The updates dataframe contains a new column:

```
ColA       ColB      NewCol
A          sun           TRUE
B          moon       FALSE
```

Comment: You are creating a new column and creating a logical condition (asking id ‘x’ is equal to ‘y’) and the value of that new column is T or F depending on if that value (‘x’).

Comment: See update, i added example (sorry still on iPad)